# What one needs to position his HTML element to allow the overflow: hidden, on the circle?

Tags: html, css

here the demo: https://codepen.io/joondoe/pen/JQPRyM

here the snippet:

```css
.circle {
  width: 15%;
  padding-bottom: 15%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border: 3px dashed salmon;
}

.circle__img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"> 
  <img src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/5MsoNXS.jpg" alt="" class="circle__img">
</div>
```

thanks for any hint

Comment: It works, what you excepted?

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina thanks for your answer, Im wondering why it doesnt works with no specifying the position, because if the img is not in absolute it should follow the classical flow, that said removing the positioning lead to the image overflow rawly the circle, that is what Im trying to understand

Comment: Ah, ok. The bound of absolute position is the closest relative position. That's it

Comment: yes but even when I remove the absolute position, and the relative position, the image stills overflows, eventually there is some element Im missing

Comment: *even when I remove the absolute position, and the relative position, the image stills overflows* --> are you sure? it not the case for me and it should not. can you show a screenshot of the result without position?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set the height of overflow hidden div. So the content determine the height of  overflow div. If you give max-height to your overflow div then content will not push the overflow div. Please see the code snippet.

```css
.circle {
  width: 15%;
  padding-bottom: 15%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 3px dashed salmon;
  max-height:0;
}

.circle img{
height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"> 
  <img src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/5MsoNXS.jpg" alt="" class="circle__img">
</div>
```